# Why are Break Points ignored in PPT VBA Script called from Actions?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I associated a shape in PowerPoint with an action that delegates to a script in VBA. In the script itself I have defined a break point and provoke an error (just for debugging purposes).

When I run the presentation and I click on the shape, the break point is ignored and no error message is displayed, the code just silently stops at the line where the error is raised.

When I run the VBA script from the event handler of a form button, VBA behaves as expected: the break point is respected and the error message pops up.

Is there an explanation, why VBA behaves differently when executing a procedure called from an action, rather than executing from an event handler or directly from the editor. More importantly: is there a cure, i.e. something I can do to get the expected behaviour in actions?

I am currently using PPT2010 under Win7, but PPT2002 shows the same behaviour.

Comment: Hi Luuklag, you just altered my text by changing the word macro to script. I dont't think that makes it any clearer! This is not just an issue of one piece of VBA code calling another piece of VBA code, but VBA code in macros associated to a shape behaves differently to VBA code called from an event.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this and similar things before.  I'm fairly sure it's deliberate ... if you're in the middle of a presentation, you wouldn't want to see error messages or worse, get dumped into the IDE, so PPT just silently fails.

Try compiling the code once before running it and even try running it manually rather than by clicking the assigned action button.

I've always found problems in my code when breakpoints fail;  as long as the code is valid and provokes no errors, the breakpoints work, even when the code's invoked from an action setting.

Comment: Hm, I've done that, but it does take some effort, because some methods (like `ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow`) raise errors when no slide show is running, so you basically have to rewrite your code to be testable by running it from the VBA editor. Also, I've had situations where this test simply did not show any errors and I was desperate to debug the action code in real life. - When you say, you've noticed similar things - in what other situations do you lose control over the code in this way?

Comment: In all cases that I can recall, the problem code wouldn't compile because of some error I'd made, or there was a runtime error, and I suspect that decent error handling would solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same PowerPoint issue when placing code behind a master slide and other code behind slides that are not master slides. This is all within the same presentation.  When calling a sub or function in the master slide from a non-master slide the master slide code executes but breaks are ignored.  I am not sure how to articulate this but it seems that the debugging 'commands' from the initiating slide are respected and acted upon as you would expect but not the master slide debugging commands because they lie in a different domain or namespace etc.  The debugging processes are only active for one 'domain'.  The master and non-master slides do not share the same domain.